# Recover Email from SD Card

Tags: email, microsoft-account, outlook

I have lost my Microsoft account login. 
Yes the login name.

I signed up with my phone and enjoyed the sync but never used the email. I have factory restored my phone.

I now cannot login as I do not know my email. My SD card still has the WPsystem folder. Is their a way to recover the email address from these files?

If you are going for the easy solution.... I have contacted Microsoft but they could not locate the email. I don't believe I signed up with 'real' info... So they could not locate it.

Again I am simply looking for the @outlook.com in the WPsystem folder.

Comment: If you can't remember the email address, could you not ask one of your friends that have emailed you in the past?

Comment: Did you link your Microsoft account with other accounts such as LinkedIn?